# How to configure PVM (parallel virtual machine)

Tags: parallels

Does anyone have same clue/reference about how to konfigure PVM (parallel virtual machine) on ubuntu..?

thx before, Your answer is very meaningful to me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. To be honest, your question reveals a lack of effort. Just googling "pvm ubuntu" gives a lot of results like this: http://varuagdiary.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/installing-pvm-on-ubuntu-1010-64bit.html (still valid for newer releases).

Comment: it's not valid complete configuration for PVM, i think PVM is very old application and it becomes very difficult to look from google maybe someone have more experience for share

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/pvm_intro.1PVM.html